# Uploading file gets Bad Request from the server

Tags: http, file-upload, content-type

I am trying to send a file using HTTP from a C++ application (no HTML-boxes). The server keeps answering Code 400/ Bad Request. 
To keep it simple, I have changed manually the content of the file to a simple string (later on, I will need to upload real binary files).

the POST request is the following:

```
POST /post.php HTTP/1.0
Host: posttestserver.com
Accept: */*
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=BOUNDARY
--BOUNDARY
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="userfile"; filename="example.txt"
Content-Type:text/plain

123ABC
--BOUNDARY--
Connection: close
```

Any idea what is going on?

Comment: There needs to be a blank line between the final HTTP header and the first `--BOUNDARY` marker.

Comment: Great, solved. Thank you.